# Pasar una columna y la tabla dinamicamente @Query JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring, jpa

Actualmente me gustaría saber como hacer una nativeQuery pasando por parametro la columna y la tabla para la creación de la query, quedando mas o menos de esta forma. Aunque no se si esto sea posible en JPA:

@Query(value = "select :columna from :tabla", nativeQuery=true)

public List obtenerPosiblesValores(String columna, String tabla);

O existe alguna otra forma de realizar esto enviando los dos parámetros. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

En `JPA`, no es posible pasar directamente el nombre de una columna o tabla como parámetro en una consulta nativa utilizando la anotación `@Query`. Sin embargo, puedes lograr esto mediante el uso de la interfaz `EntityManager` y la construcción dinámica de la consulta.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo puedes lograrlo:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

public class TuRepositorioCustomImpl implements TuRepositorioCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List obtenerPosiblesValores(String columna, String tabla) {
        String query = "SELECT " + columna + " FROM " + tabla;
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}
```

En el código anterior, TuRepositorioCustomImpl es una implementación personalizada de tu repositorio que contiene la lógica para ejecutar la consulta nativa. Se utiliza la anotación @PersistenceContext para inyectar el `EntityManager`, que es necesario para crear la consulta nativa.

Luego, dentro del método obtenerPosiblesValores, se construye dinámicamente la consulta concatenando los valores de columna y tabla. Finalmente, se ejecuta la consulta utilizando `entityManager.createNativeQuery(query)` y se obtiene el resultado mediante `getResultList()`.

Recuerda que esta solución implica el uso de consultas nativas, lo cual puede ser menos portátil y menos seguro que el uso de consultas `JPQL` estándar. Asegúrate de sanitizar y validar los parámetros adecuadamente para evitar posibles ataques de inyección SQL.

[Fuente :)](https://chat.openai.com/share/edbbeab3-2b25-4351-896c-44102b2454ca)